# How can I identify requests made via AJAX in Python's Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, angularjs, flask

I'd like to detect if the browser made a request via AJAX (AngularJS) so that I can return a JSON array, or if I have to render the template. How can I do this?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Flask comes with a `is_xhr` attribute in the `request` object.

```
from flask import request
@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home_page():
    if request.is_xhr:
        context = controllers.get_default_context()
        return render_template('home.html', **context)
```

**Notice:** This solution is deprecated and not viable anymore.

Comment: Notice that (from Flask official documentation): "This only works with libraries that support the X-Requested-With header and set it to “XMLHttpRequest”."

Comment: "'Request.is_xhr' is deprected as of flask version 0.13", the above answer is not viable anymore

Comment: @kres0345 Would you like to answer the current valid method and I'll upvote your answer?

Comment: @AlexLordThorsen I couldn't find a "proper" method for checking whether a request is of ajax origin, but I posted a workaround that worked for my purpose

Answer (score 4):

for future readers: what I do is something like below:

```
request_xhr_key = request.headers.get('X-Requested-With')
if request_xhr_key and request_xhr_key == 'XMLHttpRequest':
   #mystuff

   return result
abort(404,description="only xhlhttprequest is allowed")
```

this will give an 404 error if the request header doesn't contain 'XMLHttpRequest' value.

Comment: But note if you need make that for security you must consider that headers can changed easy.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any way to be certain whether a request is made by ajax.

What I found that worked for me, was to simply include a get parameter for xhr requests and simply omit the parameter on non-xhr requests.

For example:

- XHR Request: `example.com/search?q=Boots&api=1`
- Other Requests: `example.com/search?q=Boots`

Answer (score 0):

I used this and it works perfectly:

```py
if request.method == 'POST' and request.headers.get('X-Requested-With') == 'XMLHttpRequest':
    current_app.logger.info('Recognized an AJAX request!')
    # rest of code to handle initial page request
```